# Short life of LED parallel to Solenoid as indicator

Tags: led, parallel, circuit-protection, surge-protection

I have a relatively simple circuit: 12 V to a switch; on the other side of the switch is a solenoid and an LED in parallel. Nothing special about either component; the LED is a 20 mA typical LED rated for 12 V and the solenoid is a solenoid on an LPG gas line. The idea is when the switch is flicked, the solenoid does its thing and the LED lights up to indicate the switch is on. The LED is just from the switch to ground.

The problem is that the LED doesn't last more than a month. I can put it a brand new LED in and flip the switch and it'll light up, but after a couple of weeks the LED will die. After the first time it dies, I can turn the switch off again and then slowly ease the switch back on and the LED will gradually come back on (weird behaviour that I can't explain?). However this only works a couple of times and after that the LED is dead.

Any ideas on how to rectify this? I'm thinking the LED is getting ruined by spiking voltage but am not sure and don't know how to fix it if this is the case.

Comment: Can you provide the model number of the 12V-rated LED you are using for additional context?

Answer (score 6):

The LED may already have a series resistor, the OP states that it is "rated" for 12V.  I suspect so because without current limiting an LED wouldn't last a second with 12V across it.  In that case it may be the inductive kick from the field collapsing during turn off that is avalanching the LED and causing the short life.

To "rectify" this put a regular diode across the solenoid coil so that it's reverse biased in normal operation and carries the inductive current when the solenoid turns off.

It should be rated for more than 12V (around 30V would be good) and for the same current as the solenoid.

Comment: This is also my take as to what is killing the LED. It can take the inductive kick spikes for a while but with enough hits the silicon of the LED chip gets damaged too the point that the LED curls up and dies.

Comment: @MichaelKaras does it actually curl up? Link?

Comment: @JanDvorak - It is an "expression" as in "curl up and die". One reference is here: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/curl-up-and-die. It is also part of a boot title: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1379790.I_Think_I_ll_Just_Curl_Up_and_Die_Leehampton_2_ and there happens to be a metalcore band that goes by that name: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_Up_and_Die

Answer (score 4):

Your LED is being destroyed by the substantial voltage spike generated from the collapsing magnetic field in your solenoid when you remove power from the circuit.

The solution is simple: Add a diode across the coil "backwards" which will absorb the brief spike.  This is called a "flyback" or "snubber" diode.

Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_diode

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a 12 V LED.  However since you say your "LED" is rated for 12 V, I'll assume it's a complete assembly that includes the appropriate resistor so that the LED is run normally when 12 V is applied to the whole assembly.  I will therefore assume the LED is not being abused when lit.

The key clue is that you said this LED assembly is directly across a solenoid.  The problem is happening when the solenoid is being switched off.  The current thru a inductor (which is what the solenoid looks like electrically) can not change instantaneously.  This isn't how the physics works, but picture the current thru a inductor as having momentum.  You can't suddenly stop the flow.  When you try, you end up with a very large and short-lived spike in voltage.

When your inductor is switched off, it makes a high voltage for a short time that is reverse from the voltage that was applied to it.  When the solenoid is on, there is 12 V across it and the LED.  When the rest of the circuit attempts to shut off the inductor, it could be making 10s to 100s of volts in reverse.  This large reverse voltage is applied to the LED, which damages it each time.  Eventually it is damaged to the point of not working at all anymore during normal operation.

The solution is simple. Add a diode with reverse polarity across the inductor.  This provides a path for the inductor current to go when switched off.  The reverse voltage will only be one diode drop, which is well within the LED's ability to withstand.

[image]

L1 is the solenoid, R1 and D1 are your LED assembly, and D2 what you need to add.  D2 needs to be able to withstand the power voltage in reverse, and conduct the solenoid current in forward operation.  A ordinary 1 A 50 V diode should work.

Answer (score -1):

Your LED is likely being destroyed by overcurrent and thermal failure. You need a series resistor with the LED to limit the current to 20mA. For a 12V source, put a ~1kΩ resistor in series with the LED.

Comment: He says the LED is rated for 12 V. It's probably an auto (as in vehicle) 12 V indicator (not a turn-signal) lamp. This is getting confusing.

Comment: If they put a 12 Volts across a 2~3 volt led, it wouldn't last 1 minute let alone 1 month.